# Android 13 RECEIVER_EXPORTED's explanation is correct?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-13

This is what google explains about RECEIVER_EXPORTED, RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED:

> Choose whether the broadcast receiver should be exported and visible
> to other apps on the device. If this receiver is listening for
> broadcasts sent from the system or from other apps—even other apps
> that you own—use the RECEIVER_EXPORTED flag. If instead this receiver
> is listening only for broadcasts sent by your app, use the
> RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag.

When I want to use broadcasts sent from the system Google says I need to use RECEIVER_EXPORTED but when I tested with `"android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"` and `"RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED"`.
I received a broadcast event.
Can anyone explain that sentence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There might be an error in their document or they changed their mind, because according to [ContextCompat documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#registerReceiver(android.content.Context,android.content.BroadcastReceiver,android.content.IntentFilter,java.lang.String,android.os.Handler,int)), you can use:

> RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED if you only want your receiver to be able to receive broadcasts **from the system** or your own app.

In my opinion, it's safer like this, because we don't want our receiver to be open to all applications just to get system broadcasts.

(edited) I found also this [on the RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED()):

> Has the same behavior as marking a statically registered receiver with "exported=false"

And when I look at [receiver documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element), for the exported attribute, I read:

> If "false", the only messages the broadcast receiver can receive are those sent by the system, components of the same application, or applications with the same user ID

So I'm confident enough that the implementation is coherent and there is a small error in the documentation

Comment: And how to unregister this broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 13):

I'm getting this error:

> Must be one or more of: Context.RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS,
> android.content.Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED,
> android.content.Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED

even though I have it set to `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` and I get the same error if I set it to `RECEIVER_EXPORTED`. It's as if I'm not satisfying the `@RegisterReceiverFlags` interface.

[image: Must be one or more of: Context.RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS, android.content.Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED, android.content.Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED]

It suggests `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` as preferred initially, but when it shows this error, it offers that I change it to `RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS`. If I set it to that, it takes away the error but then highlights it in yellow and suggests that I add one of the other two… which still error if I include multiple flags.

**EDIT:** Okay, I fixed this by using `ContextCompat.registerReceiver()` instead of regular `registerReceiver()` which also requires using `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` instead of `Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error after implementing all the above said code, any guess why it is giving the error

Comment: `ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, alarmReceiver, IntentFilter("ACTION_ALLOW_ALARMS_PERMISSION"), ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)`

This worked out for me

Comment: @OrcunSevsay where did you add it ?

Comment: @Moeez in MainActivity