# Build got successful and application could launch

Tags: android, sdk

Issue happening:

Build got successful and application could launch. But as soon as the app launches, the app crashes. The Bug Report says the below,

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.aptean.tms.pod: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace

Previously:  Supports below SDK,

kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"

buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"

```
minSdkVersion = 21

compileSdkVersion = 31

targetSdkVersion = 30
```

Requirement: To support SDK version 34(Android 14)

Changes made so far,

```
kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"

buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"

minSdkVersion = 23

compileSdkVersion = 34

targetSdkVersion = 34

 

dependencies {

        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-rc01')

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'        

    }
```

Comment: *Please used this link*
[API level 34 - android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76887498/basic-view-activity-in-android-studio-error/76887999#76887999)

Answer (score 0):

Look at how you're registering your broadcast receiver for Android 13 or higher.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74272587/android13-receiver-exporteds-explanation-is-correct) to another question may help you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also trying to update the app to support Android 14 and facing similar issue.

```
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
        applicationContext, CustomBroadcastReceiver(),
        filter,
        ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    )
```

any resolution?

Comment: This should be a question or comment not an answer.